# Do high-temperature rated coin cells exist?

Tags: batteries, battery-chemistry

I'm currently working on a project that will implement a coin cell as its primary power source. My PCB will likely be exposed to high temperatures ranging from 100C upwards. Now I realize that I will likely need a proper enclosure along with other cooling capabilities, however, I would still like to select the highest temperature rated coin cell possible.

So I'm curious if anyone is aware of coin cells that possess high temperature ratings. Also, what would determine whether or not a coin cell possesses high temperature rating? Would it primarily be based upon battery type (alkaline, lithium, etc.), or would it depend primarily on how the battery was manufactured?

Thanks!

Comment: 100°C upwards is a tad unspecific. Like 1000°C or like 110°C?

Comment: It could range from 100C to 500C.

Comment: Are the other components on your PCB rated for operation at 500C? If so, can you let us know what they are.

Comment: @Barry No. Everything else is just rated ~125C. Essentially I'm just trying to find a type of coin cell that is also rated for this temperature. Temperatures that exceed 125C will force me to provide protection for my PCB via enclosure/insulation/cooling. I just haven't been able to find an adequate coin cell until Ignacio responded with an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lithium thionyl chloride primary cells have been rated up to 150degC, but you will need to consult the manufacturer with regards to cell size and actual temperature rating.